# Execute script as part of mvn package

Tags: maven, war

My `pom.xml` contains

```
    <plugin>                                                            
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>                                          
            <configuration>                                                 
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <outputDirectory>${wlp.install.dir}/usr/servers/liberty/apps</outputDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>            
    </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn package` I can see this step running:

> [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) @ frontEnd ---

That's great.  However, I also want to run a shell script *before* the `war` file is created.  I tried adding

```
<plugin>                                                            
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>                    
    <version>1.7</version>                                          
    <configuration>                                                 
        <tasks>                                                     
            <exec dir="${basedir}"
                executable="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/concat"/>
        </tasks>                                                    
    </configuration>                                                
</plugin>
```

before the `maven-war` plugin, but it does not run.  I don't even see `antrun` in the output of `mvn`.  Adding the `<tasks>` element to the `<configuration>` for `maven-war-plugin` does nothing either.

What can I do to have maven simply run a script as part of `mvn package`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position in the pom.xml is irrelevant, you have to bind the maven-antrun-plugin execution to the correct lifecycle phase (e.g. compile) as shown below:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase> <!-- a lifecycle phase --> </phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>

            <!--
              Place any Ant task here. You can add anything
              you can add between <target> and </target> in a
              build.xml.
            -->

          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

See [The maven-antrun-plugin Usage Page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) for more details and [The Maven Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for further reference.

Comment: How do I know which phase I can use?

Comment: As you want your ant-plugin executed before the package phase where the war-plugin runs you have to choose an earlier lifecycle phase. It depends on the prerequisites of your ant-plugin call which phase to choose. The compile phase seems a good bet.

Comment: I should also note that `<exec>` should be a child of `<target>`, not `<tasks>`